# Laravel 4 - Change (upload imagename)

Tags: php, image, upload, laravel-4

I'd like to rename images using random name.
Do I have to use some logic encryption?

I have the function in my Controller postAdd to upload an image and save some information:

```
    public function postAdd()
    {
     $path = 'uploads/noticias';
     $file = Input::file('archivo'); 
     $archivo=$file->getClientOriginalName();
     $extension =$file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
     $tamano=$file->getSize();
     $upload = $file->move($path, $archivo);
     if($upload)
     {
         $inputs=Input::All();
         $n= new Noticias;
        $n->titulo = $inputs["titulo"];
        $n->contenido=$inputs["contenido"];
        $n->seo_slug=$inputs["titulo"];
        $n->fecha=date("Y-m-d");
        $n->foto=$archivo;
        $n->save();
        return Redirect::to('add');
     }else
     {
        return Redirect::to('add');
     }
    }
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filename should contain extension as well.
To create filename, generate random string and append extension from uploaded file.
Preferably, lower the character case (or do upprecase , but keep it the same)
In the example I posted for you I use `value` function, which return the result from whatever you pass into - in this case I pass anonymous function, which generates the filename.

```
public function postAdd()
{
    $path = 'uploads/noticias';
    $file = Input::file('archivo'); 
    $archivo = value(function() use ($file){
        $filename = str_random(10) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        return strtolower($filename);
    });
    $tamano = $file->getSize();
    $upload = $file->move($path, $archivo);
    if($upload) {
        $inputs=Input::All();
        $n= new Noticias;
        $n->titulo = $inputs["titulo"];
        $n->contenido=$inputs["contenido"];
        $n->seo_slug=$inputs["titulo"];
        $n->fecha=date("Y-m-d");
        $n->foto=$archivo;
        $n->save();
        return Redirect::to('add');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('add');
    }
}
```

## **Edit**

Explanations, as requested in comment...

***value*** function:
To be clear, it is not the native PHP function. It is one of Laravel's helper functions - info [here](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#miscellaneous).
This is its source. It either executes closure (anonymous function) if closure is passed, or just returns what is passed (value).

```
 /**
 * Return the default value of the given value.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return mixed
 */
function value($value)
{
 return $value instanceof Closure ? $value() : $value;
}
```

I chose to use this to make code more readable. `$filename` variable used inside the closure, is modified and returned - nothing from closure is needed outside of it.
Plus, you can use `$filename` variable in scope of `postAdd` function and they just don't mix, it is not possible their values are overwriten by accident, and so on...

Comment: thanks for your answer, very useful. I wonder if you could explain something... I see your using an anonymous php function but what's the part it's enclosed in for? The part named `value()`. I'm really confused as to what this is doing, and couldn't see anything in php docs called value. Couldn't one just call the anonymous function without it and it would still work okay?

Comment: Hi there, I added explanation to original answer. Hope, it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, highly appreciate it and your speedy reply too! Hope I can find a time to use it in my applications for laravel. :)

Comment: No problem! I use it more than I would say before. Use it, but use if wisely (like anything else) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
'str_random'
```

Generate a random string of the given length.

```
$string = str_random(40);//random string of length 40
```

http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#strings